# Hadoop importing data - right ETL approach

Tags: hadoop, import, hive, hdfs, etl

I'm started to learning Hadoop Stack for one of my projects (quite newbie in hadoop stack). I try to figure out what's the best approach for ETL process for putting data in HIVE. I have some working solution, but I suppose it's not optimal, and there are better options.

My Case: 
I have a raw data in binary files generated by system. Before putting them on HDFS/HIVE  I have to parse them using unix console program (quite complex) for text lines with data, and then place it to HIVE table.

My current solution:

1. System add a message to Kafka that there is a new binary file waiting for processing.
2. I have a python script on hadoop master node (at least for now):

   A) recieveing Kafka messages

   B) downloading the file.

   C) executing the console program

   D) Saving text output to CSV

   E) Pushing CSV file to HDFS

   F) Creating temporary table in HIVE from CSV File

   G) INSERT data from temporary TABLE into seperate pernament table on ORC engine

   H)  Delete temporary table

My Questions:

1. Is this flow optimal? Maybe there is something which could be simplier?
2. It this possible to schedule/deploy/execute this python script (or other better technology?) automatically on every hadoop node?
3. Any clues about tools/options to make the whole process easy to maintenance, schedule, and efficient?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume your point 2 - > D has a constant layout for csv.  In That
>   case , You may combine points F and H , rather than creating and
>   dropping table every-time , You can create a template temp-table and
>   overwrite data every next time.

For Eg :

```
create external table  template
(
---- Your csv schema. 
)
```

Next you may try following type of insert :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '%s' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE template;
```

This will reduce some time in your processing.

I am not sure about java , but i have used lot of python and have implemented these similar requirements at my work. I never felt any challenges with python due to its diversity and different modules available.

> If you are implementing this in UNIX box , you may either use cron or
>   oozie to schedule the whole automation.

Comment: Thx for clues. 
Table now is created by: 

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS template
(
---- CVS Schema
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','     STORED AS TEXTFILE     location`
Where location is path to HDFS CSV file. 

After this, I use: 
`INSERT INTO TABLE target_table SELECT * FROM template; 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS template;`